# Compiler issue with Clang 3.2 or am I doing it wrong? (variadic templates & default parameters)

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, variadic-templates

I've gone a bit deep with template programming in my latest library rewrite, and so I made template that assembles bitmasks which I want to use as a method parameter initializer:

```
test_scanner( unsigned int avec = CtrlVec<'\n','\r'>::mask ) ;
```

This works with GCC 4.8, but I get a series of errors from clang 3.2:

```
error: expected parameter declarator
error: expected ')'
error: expected '>'
```

Putting a () around CtrlVec fixes the problem.  What I am curious is, does it work in later versions of Clang or should I submit this as a possible error in the compiler, or am I doing something wrong?

The entire test case is here:

```
namespace test
{
    // template magic for building a bit mask from control characters
  template <char...> struct CtrlVec ; 
  template <char c> struct CtrlVec<c>
  { 
    static_assert( ( c < 0x20 ), "Only for control characters" ) ; 
    enum { mask = ( 1 << c ) } ; 
  } ; 
  template <char c, char... cs> struct CtrlVec<c, cs...>
  { 
    static_assert( ( c < 0x20 ), "Only for control characters" ) ; 
    enum { mask = ( 1 << c ) | CtrlVec<cs...>::mask } ; 
  } ; 

  static_assert( CtrlVec<'\0', '\001', '\002'>::mask == 0x7, "") ; 

    /// 

  class test_scanner
  { 
    public:
          // this version works fine in GCC, but gives an error in Clang 3.2
      test_scanner( unsigned int avec = CtrlVec<'\n','\r'>::mask ) ;

          // adding the () makes it work
      test_scanner( int good, unsigned int avec = ( CtrlVec<'\n','\r'>::mask ) ) ; 
  } ; 

} ;

int main() {}
```

or you can pull it from github:

https://github.com/woolstar/test/blob/master/misc/testinitargs.cpp

Comment: Compiles fine on clang++3.4 trunk 193040

Comment: Thanks @DyP, I was hoping it was just a temporary problem.  I'll make a note to myself to clean out the ()s once Ubuntu upgrades.

Comment: @DyP interesting. same problem on Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn). Its 3.3-based, so not shocking.

Comment: @WhozCraig The problem is still present even in coliru's 3.4 trunk 18...